# how to get the object from ng-repeat checkbox values in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm encountering a problem and I will appreciate someone can help.

Right now I'm showing several checkboxes in my form which are grabbing from my firebase database. And in my controller I'm trying to use ng-submit to store whole data of form.
My checkbox JSON format should look like this.

```
{
    "apple" : true,
    "spotify" : true 
}
```

[The checkbox image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phsq3.jpg)

okay the following is my code from HTML and Javascript

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="hashtag in hashtags" for="{{hashtag}}">
  <input type="checkbox" name="{{hashtag.$value}}" id="{{hashtag.$value}}" value="{{hashtag.$value}}" ng-model="hashtag.SELECTED" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"> 
    {{hashtag.$value | capitalize}}
</label>
```

My Javascript here

```
form.$add({
    description: $scope.inputDescription,
    hashtags: {
        *I don't know how to put checkbox's result here.*
    },
    time: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    title: $scope.inputTitle,
    url: $scope.inputUrl
})
```

Anyone can help, please? Thank you so much.

**Update**
Thanks for the reply. I really appreciate those! However, I found out that I forgot to mention something and I tried the answers from the reply and they didn't work. The picture below will explain my problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAyRU.jpg)
Thank you so much!

**Finally solution** in case people are curious about the answer I just figured out. The following is my solution. Thank you guys! I love stackoverflow!

```
function checkbox(hashtags) {
    var arr = {};
    for(var hashtag in hashtags) {
        if(hashtags[hashtag].SELECTED === true){
            arr[hashtags[hashtag].$value] = true;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: is `hashtags` the first described JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, I found info in a similar question:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="check(hashtags)"/>

$scope.check= function(data) { 
var arr = [];
for(var i in data){
   if(data[i].SELECTED=='Y'){
       arr.push(data[i].value);
   }
}
//At this points you have all the selected hashtags on arr Array
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much Chris! I did it. At first I used you answer but somehow just didn't work. And I used this answer again and twitch a little bit and it works this time! Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `ng-model` to

```
ng-model="mhashtags[hashtag.$value]"
```

With this you will have a `mhashtags` variable in your scope that will be exactly what you need to send.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **hashtags** is this JSON:

```
$scope.hashtags = {
  "apple" : true,
  "spotify" : true 
};
```

I would change the ng-repeat to this:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="(hashtag, bool) in hashtags" for="{{hashtag}}">
  <input type="checkbox" name="{{hashtag}}" id="{{hashtag}}" ng-value="bool" ng-model="hashtag"> 
    {{hashtag | capitalize}}
</label>
```

**hashtag** is the key of the object and **bool** is the value, so no need for "$value".